# How the selection happens in 'InfoGainAttributeEval' in weka feature selection (filter method)

Tags: machine-learning, weka, feature-extraction, feature-selection

I am currently using 'InfoGainAttributeEval' for feature selection. I want to know what happens in that method. I found the following.

Evaluates the worth of an attribute by measuring the information gain with respect to the class.

InfoGain(Class,Attribute) = H(Class) - H(Class | Attribute).

As I am new to this area I don't understand what it is. Can someone please explain me how it works? :) What is the difference of this with 'GainRationAttributeEval'

Answer (score 10):

InfoGainAttributeEval (and GainRatioAttributeEval) are both used for **feature selection tasks**.

What InfoGainAttributeEval basically does is measuring how each feature contributes in *decreasing the overall entropy*.

Let's take an example. Say we have this dataset :

```
------------------------------------------
temperature | wind | class
high        | low  | play
low         | low  | play
high        | low  | play
low         | high | cancelled
low         | low  | play
high        | high | canceled
high        | low  | play
```

The Entropy, H(X), is defined as follows :

```
H(X) = -sum(Pi*log2(Pi))
```

, with Pi being the probability of the class i in the dataset, and log2 the base 2 logarithm (in Weka natural logarithm of base *e* is used, but generally we take log2). Entropy basically measures the **degree of "impurity"**. The closest to 0 it is, the less impurity there is in your dataset.

Hence, a good attribute is an attribute that **contains the most information**, i.e, **reduces the most the entropy**. The InfoGainAttributeEval method of Weka is a way of evaluating exactly this.

Now, the entropy of our example is : 
    H(Class) = -(5/7*log2(5/7)+2/7*log(2/7)) = 0,863.

Let's calculate for our example the amount of information carried by the temperature attribute.

InfoGain(Class,Temperature) = H(Class) - H(Class | Temperature).

To get the H(Class | Temperature), we need to split the dataset according to this attribute.

```
                            Dataset
                             /   \
                            /     \
                           / Temp° \
                          /         \
                         /           \
                        /             \
                      high           low



    temperature | wind | class                 temperature|wind|class
high        | low  | play                      low     | low|play
high        | low  | play                      low     | high|cancelled
high        | high | cancelled                 low     | low |play
high        | low  | play
```

Each branch here has its own entropy. We need to first calculate the entropy of each split.

```
H(left_split) = -(3/4log(3/4)+1/4log(1/4) = 0,811
H(right_split) = -(1/3log(1/3)+2/3log(2/3) = 0,918
```

H(Class | Temperature) is then equals to the sum of both children's entropy, weighted by the proportion of instances that where taken from the parent dataset. In short :

```
H(Class | Temperature) = 4/7*H(left_split) + 3/7*H(right_split).
```

You then have everything to calculate the InfoGain.
In this example, it's 0,06 bits. This means that the temperature feature only reduces the global entropy by 0,06 bits, the **feature's contribution to reduce the entropy**  (= the **information gain**) is fairly small.

This is pretty obvious looking at the instances in the dataset, as we can see at a first glance that the temperature doesn't affect much the final class, unlike the wind feature.

As for the **GainRatioAttributeEval**, it's an enhancement of the InfoGain, with a normalized score.

Hope that helps !

Source for part of this answer : Anuj Sharma and Shubhamoy Dey. Article: Performance Investigation of Feature Selection Methods and Sentiment Lexicons for Sentiment Analysis. IJCA Special Issue on Advanced Computing and Communication Technologies for HPC Applications ACCTHPCA(3):15-20, July 2012.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation, I have a doubt, in `H(Class | Temperature) = 4/7*H(left_split) + 3/7*H(right_split).`, wouldn't it be `H(Class | Temperature) = 5/7*H(left_split) + 2/7*H(right_split).`, as in the first example, when you first compute `H(Class)`?